# lxml,Python. I can't get content of element: element.text is None

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I loaded a xml file from internet, and parsed with lxml. But I couldn't get the content by `'element'.text`. Both result and source are short, I will just write them.

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
<product>
<company><![CDATA[google]]></company>
<link><![CDATA[http://www.google.com]]></link>
<subject><![CDATA[sushi]]></subject>
</product>
</products>
```

Code :

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

rss = urllib2.urlopen("http://dizzy-v.co.kr/test/test.xml").read()
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(rss), etree.HTMLParser())

root = tree.getroot()
for product in root.iter('product'):
    for element in product.iter():
        print element.text
```

result :

```
None
None
None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `etree.HTMLParser` gives you texts:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> from lxml import etree
>>>
>>> rss = urllib2.urlopen("http://dizzy-v.co.kr/test/test.xml").read()
>>> root = etree.fromstring(rss) # <----
>>> for product in root.iter('product'):
...     for element in product.iter():
...         print element.text
...


google
http://www.google.com
sushi
```